# Why is Shell redirecting the stdout of a python script into my shell variable?

Tags: python, shell

I am following another old post to solve a problem that i have. My python script returns a value and I wanted it to be retrieved by my shell script. so i followed this tip:

*You can print your value in Python, like this:*

```
print fooPy()
```

*and in your shell script:*

```
fooShell=$(python fooPy.py)
```

Problem is every `sys.stdout` from my python is being stored in `fooShell`. So my variable has all the output, but not the variable that i wanted to return. Do you have any tips?

EDIT: I have a simple "`return variable`" at the end of my python script. I needed the shell script to call the python and get the variable calculated by it. How could i transfer a variable from a python environement to a shell one?

Comment: Scripts don't have return values, they have exit codes and output, so there seems to be some misunderstanding here. Can you explain more precisely what you are trying to do? (As to why your sys.stdout goes into the shell variable, that's what the `$()` construct does...)

Comment: Processes communicate with each other via stdio channels. shells and common *nix utilities are particularly good at this (think shell pipelines `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`) -- imagine how difficult/unsafe it would be for the shell to reach into the memory of the python process to extract the value.

Comment: And as Ture comments, that's how [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected that all `stdout` of `python fooPy.py` will be saved to `fooShell`. If you want to isolate the value returned by this function and get it in shell, you can save it to a file, like this

```
f = open('fooPy.txt','w')
f.write(str(fooPy))
f.close()
```

and then in your shell script

```
fooShell=$(cat fooPy.txt)
rm fooPy.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, seems unusual, i'll try that. Is this the only way to communicate a value between environments?